# Onkeyup on every form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am making a form with 4 input fields , 2 date picker and 3 select fields. I want to add onkeyup event on every field present in form. When user fill more than 2 field, result start showing in div named result with the help of ajax. I mean when ever i change any field data will populate live in div with ajax.

```
$('#form input,select').keyup(function() {
    if ($('#from').val() !== '' && $('#to').val() !== '' && $('#depa').val() !== '' && $('#arr').val() !== '') {
           $.get('ajaxSearch.php', $("#form").serialize(), function(data) { $('#result').html(data); });
    } else {

    }
});
```

I tried but some field post with ajax but not all of them and if i change again it doesn't work again

Comment: i just asked a question, why negative point, is it the format of code than everybody have a different style of writing code

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
 Change

```
$('#form input,select').keyup(function() {
```

to

```
 $('form').change(function() {
```

Make sure that you are using **jquery 1.4 or higher**

Comment: Could you please try $('#form').change(function() {

Answer (score 1):

Just Copy paste below code... 
It might solve your problem.

```
$('#form input,select').keyup(function() {
    var count=0;
    $("input").each(function(){
        if($(this).val()!="") {
            count++;
        }
        if(count>1) {
            $.get('ajaxSearch.php', $("#form").serialize(), function(data) { $('#result').html(data); });
        }
        else{
            $("#result").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: not working only post first two input fields values, but dont post others

Comment: actually i have many field, your code dont work when i change any of the fields value again, your code runs just one time

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'on' with 'change'.

```
$("#form").on("change", ":input", function(){alert('changed some element');});
```